# What is the structure of *.bin files ( also called Late Data files) in Historian Wonderware Server?

Tags: wonderware, historian

I'm trying to parse *.bin file of Late Data. I found out some meanings of some group of bytes (look at the picture), but some group of bytes I could't veryfied (in red circles). Does anyone knows what are they mean?
[image]